# Is the SX1278 SPI interface 5v tolerant?

Tags: spi, wireless, datasheet, level-shifting, lora

I want to connect the SX1278 LoRa module with its SPI interface to a microcontroller.

[My module](http://www.ebay.de/itm/AI-Thinker-LoRa-433MHz-RF-Wireless-Transceiver-Modul-SX1278-mit-Antenna-Ra-01-/272655833463?hash=item3f7b8dd977:g:i6QAAOSwI7tZxbKp)

[Datasheet](http://ecksteinimg.de/Datasheet/SX1278.pdf)

But in the datasheet I haven't found anything about the maximum digital input voltage. Just the maximum supply voltage. The module runs on 3.3v but my microcontroller runs on 5v and I would love to avoid using a level shifter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reference to the maximum voltage either.

I would not expect it to be 5V tolerant.

Even if it is tolerant on the inputs a 3.3v device cannot be guaranteed to drive a processor driven from 5V.  The worst case VinH for the processor is probably 70% of the 5V VCC = 3.5V.  A '1' from the receiver may be interpreted as a '0' by the processor.

I would recommend using level shifters.

For 5V - 3.3V conversion it could be as simple as a resistive divider but you will need an active device on the 3.3V - 5V shifting.  At moderate speeds a single FET could do the job in the classic level shifting arrangement such as used here:

[Level shifter[1](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009)